# Unsuccessful SQL dump import in PgAdmin 4 MacOS

Tags: sql, postgresql, dump, pgadmin-4

I have to use SQL for the very first time. I downloaded data from French Public Service Open Data (https://cerema.app.box.com/v/dvfplus-opendata/folder/160785684885). I also downloaded Postgres App and PgAdmin 4. The file of interest is a dump, with a .sql extension. I created a database called "DVF" directly in PgAdmin.

[image]

Following all the tutorials online and the help here I tried to import the file using "Backup" and "Restore" commands, as well as lines directly from the terminal. I have a "success" message when I use Backup or Restore in PgAdmin, but always an error message from the Terminal (by clicking on DVF in Postgres App).

```
[DVF=# ./psql -U postgres DVF < /Users/Menica/dpts.sql;
>ERROR : syntax error at or near "."

[DVF=# psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d DVF -f dpts.sql;
>ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
```

Furthermore, even with "success" messages from Backup/Restore, my tables aren't in PgAdmin after the Refresh.

I don't know if it can help but here are some directories :

The file : /Users/Menica/dpts.sql

PostGres App : /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3
=> There is a lot of folders there, like "bin"

Terminal by default : /bin/zhs

**UPDATE**

To dump the database I used the following in psql :

```
DVF-# pg_dump DVF > /Users/Menica/dpts.sql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pgdump"
LINE 1: pg_dump DVF > /Users/Menica/dpts.sql
        ^
```

The first 25 lines of the dpts.sql file are the following :

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.5.25
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.25

-- Started on 2022-04-14 15:50:09 CEST

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- TOC entry 34 (class 2615 OID 631938251)
-- Name: dvf_d2a; Type: SCHEMA; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE SCHEMA dvf_d2a;


--
-- TOC entry 35 (class 2615 OID 632173840)
-- Name: dvf_d2b; Type: SCHEMA; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE SCHEMA dvf_d2b;


SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;
```

[image]

Comment: I have no clue.. I downloaded Postgres yesterday so it's the last version available for Mac (v2.5.8 ; PostGRESQL 14.4)...

Comment: I only use R and STATA on a daily basis so it's completely new for me and I don't understand a single thing concerning SQL

Comment: I obtain this : "PostgreSQL 14.4 on aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9), 64-bit"

Comment: `[DVF=#` indicates you are already in `psql` so you cannot invoke `psql` inside it.  Use `\i  /Users/Menica/dpts.sql`. per [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver `The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database.` So do I have to type something like `pg_restore /Users/Menica/dpts.sql` in the Terminal ? /// Tried it `pg_restore /Users/Menica/dpts.sql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_restore"`

Comment: No, [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) is its own command line program. Read the information at the link for how to use. It is provided by [postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html). Though if you do the restore through `pgAdmin4` I would say do that, until you have more experience.

Comment: _pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql._ My bad

Comment: Are you using the same input file? It cannot be both a custom format and a text format.

Comment: Yes I just have one file to import and it's a .sql one with lines of code in it to create tables.

Comment: To your question add 1) The command for dumping the data. 2) A text copy and paste of the first 25 lines of the `dpts.sql` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246073/discussion-between-adrian-klaver-and-mmcr-economics).